# How can i make a click event on v-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-select

I am using vue-select and I wanna make a click event when i select a item from the select list. I tried with `@change="changedValue" @selected="changedLabel"` but that does not works for me.

Vue select

```
<v-select placeholder="Add administrator" class="form-control-select" label="displayName" :options="items"></v-select>
```

Does anyone know how to trigger an event? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you did not provide a link to the component library you are using I'll assume you are using [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select).

A quick look trough its source shows the component has an [onChange prop](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/blob/173f0bfea09199c15d1d494d19fb92e4f10aa963/src/components/Select.vue#L544) which is called when the selected value changes and defaults to emitting the input event.

You can simply attach your `changedLabel` to `@input`:

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [      
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ],
    selected: null
  },
  methods: {
    changedLabel(event) {
      this.selected = event;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-select 
    placeholder="Add administrator" 
    class="form-control-select" 
    label="displayName" 
    :options="items"
    @input="changedLabel"
  ></v-select> 
  
  <span>{{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If the event is just to rewrite a Vue.data variable (in example `this.selected`), then `v-model` is quicker [https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting)